# How to create, write to, and check files in C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating an application in Visual Studio 2017 and I am having issues creating files, writing to them the correct message, and checking if the file exists.

The issue I am running in to is that the logic I have believes that the file already exists even though the file has been deleted. When I run the program the given file is created but it always includes `FILE EXISTS`.  I am stumped and any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

I have outputted the directory in previous tests so I know that it is the correct directory to the file

```cs
public void createFile(String name)
{
      String dirpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
      StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(name);

      if (!File.Exists(dirpath + @"\" + name))
            file.Write("FILE DOES NOT EXIST AND HAS BEEN CREATED");
      else
            file.Write("FILE EXISTS");

      file.Close();
}
```

I expect the output to be `FILE DOES NOT EXISTS AND HAS BEEN CREATED` but the actual output is always `FILE EXISTS`

Comment: Could it be that the `StreamWriter` isn't using `dirpath` but `File.Exists` *is* using dirpath?

Comment: Protip: I recommend that this function accepts a fully qualified path and works with that directly instead of constructing paths itself.

Comment: I've tried using `dirpath` within `StreamWriter` as well and it is still running into the same problem as it believes the file already exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs of [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_)

> The path parameter can be a file name, including a file on a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) share. If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.

Looks like as soon as you make the `StreamWriter` the file gets created.

Comment: After reading the documentation you are correct, I have corrected the problem by putting `StreamWriter` within each step of the logic of the `If Statement` Would there possibly be a better way to do this than `StreamWriter`?

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as the solution (the check mark under the voting arrows for my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static properties of the [File Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2) to write to the file. Also, don't compose filenames yourself but use `Path.Combine(directory, name)` and make sure to use the same path in `Exists` as for the file creation.

```
public void createFile(string name)
{
    string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string path = Path.Combine(directory, name);

    if (File.Exists(path)) {
        File.WriteAllText(path, "FILE EXISTS");
    } else {
        File.WriteAllText(path, "FILE DID NOT EXIST AND HAS BEEN CREATED");
    }
}
```

Note that I have inverted the two if-cases. I prefer to ask a positive question and to handle a positive answer in the if-part and a negative one in the else-part. It's somehow confusing to ask a negative question and when the answer is negative it means that we have a positive situation.

If the file exists, you could also append the text, instead of overwriting the file:

```
File.AppendAllText(path, "FILE EXISTS");
```